# Conditional definitions in scheme (lisp)

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, procedure

```
(define (smallest x y z)
  (define min x)
  (cond ((< y min) (define min y))
        ((< z min) (define min z))
        (se (define min x)))
  min)
```

I'm trying to create a short procedure which returns the smallest of three numbers. It seems like the expression in a conditional can't be a definition, because I'm getting this error:

```
 begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in:
  (begin (define min y))
  (define min y)
```

Do you have any suggestions on what I'm in fact doing wrong, is the problem using a definition for the expression portion?  If that's so, how would you tackle the problem?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code in the question:

- The last condition should be an `else`, not `se`.
- You should not name a variable `min`, this name conflicts with a built-in procedure with the same name.
- You can't `define` a variable in arbitrary places, `define` is only allowed at the beginning of the procedure. To change an already existing value, use `set!` - but wait! you should avoid using `set!` as much as possible, in Scheme we prefer functional-programming style solutions, and mutating variables is heavily discouraged.
- The algorithm isn't right to begin with. Notice that only *one* of the conditions in a `cond` will get executed, and there's no way to determine the minimum of three numbers with just one comparison!

The simplest way to solve this problem in Scheme would be:

```
(define (smallest x y z)
  (min x y z))
```

If you want to implement it by hand, it's possible with a couple more comparisons:

```
(define (smallest x y z)
  (cond ((and (<= x y) (<= x z)) x)
        ((and (<= y x) (<= y z)) y)
        (else z)))
```

Comment: Thanks! yeah, I'm just on the first chapter of the SICP and didn't know about the min function yet. appreciate the pointers on avoiding functional style programming.  it's interesting to learn about best practices for a language that's so different from what I'm used to.

Comment: @lincoln No worries! you'll get the hang of it :) . I updated my answer with a functional-style solution.